# How to display the attribute value in an information window?

Tags: pyqgis, pyqt

The following code is used to test if a selected object from layer A is inside an object from another layer B. Depending on the result, a window is displayed and indicates the answer.

The object selected in layer A has several attributes including its name 'geo_parcelle'
I don't know how to display it.
I replaced `????` by `layer2.getFeatures(geo_parcelle)` but it doesn't work.
does anyone have an idea?

```
from qgis.PyQt import QtWidgets

layer1 = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('1')[0] 
layer2 = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('2')[0]

for feature in layer1.getSelectedFeatures(): 
    if feature.geometry().within(layer2.aggregate(aggregate=19,fieldOrExpression='$geometry')[0]):
        QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(None, 'la parcelle ',  ???? + 'IN Z')
    else:
        QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(None, 'la parcelle ',  ???? + 'OUT Z')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the attribute you are trying to access is in your layer A/layer1, then you already have a reference to the feature and you can access its 'geo_parcelle' attribute with `feature['geo_parcelle']` and use string formatting to insert this value into your message box information string like this:

```py
from qgis.PyQt import QtWidgets

layer1 = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('1')[0] 
layer2 = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('2')[0]

for feature in layer1.getSelectedFeatures(): 
    if feature.geometry().within(layer2.aggregate(aggregate=19,fieldOrExpression='$geometry')[0]):
        QMessageBox.information(None, 'la parcelle', f'{feature["geo_parcelle"]} IN Z')
    else:
        QMessageBox.information(None, 'la parcelle', f'{feature["geo_parcelle"]} OUT Z')
```

Comment: Thank you !  I replaced the f' with the str function and it works perfectly.                              
         [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9Rxd.jpg

Comment: @fcka, you don't need the `str()` function here. You can see in your image that you are getting the curly braces showing up in your 
string. You should read up on Python f-strings: https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/#f-strings-a-new-and-improved-way-to-format-strings-in-python. With f-string formatting, the statement inside the curly braces is evaluated and the returned value is inserted into the string.